# Chrome drop-shadow box appears over div

Tags: google-chrome, z-index, css

I'm trying to make shadow appear under my div. So far it works on anything except chrome/chromium.
To put it simply the div that draws the shadows isn't shown as it should, even though z-index property is set the **shadow appears over** a div. Html looks like that:

```
<body>  
<div id="header" class="box clear">
    <div id="logo">
       <img class="obraz_srodek" src="http://ocento.hol.es/tz/logotyp.png" title="ocentologotype"/>

    </div>

</div>
<div class="content">// Javascript/jQuery soon</div>​​​
<div id="test">Padding test</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

My css file is like that:

```
body
{
background-image:url('bg.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat;
}

html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 98%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width:98%;

}

.content{
    padding-top:55px;

}

.obraz_srodek {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:25px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top:7px;

}
#header
{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 40px;
    min-width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;


}

.box {
  position: relative;

  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
  border-radius: 1%     1%     1%     1% /     1%     1%     1%     1%;
}
.box:after {
      position: absolute;
      width: 80%;
      height: 40%;
      left: 10%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: -4;
      bottom: 0%;
      content: "";
      box-shadow: 0 7px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
      }
```

Comment: the shadow should appear under which div?

Comment: move "box-shadow: 0 7px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);" from .box:after to #header

Comment: @ChamingaD if I do that the shadows obviously appears, but the CSS I've created is supposed to round the shadow by drawing the box beneath. The way you've put it it only draw a bottom shadow, which is not what I expect.

Comment: @Pete header div is supposed to have a shadow drawn by a box beneath it. It does, but the box appears OVER the header in Chrome (only in chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethings like this ? I moved div.box for effect, chrome cant do it with you're method
[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/StxnT/2/)

```
<div id="header" class="clear">
    <div class="box">
        <div id="logo">
            <img class="obraz_srodek" src="http://ocento.hol.es/tz/logotyp.png" title="ocentologotype"/>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it sir! I've made such a mistake and balmed for the z-index. Sorry for that, now it works as expected. 
Thank you.